# Why does nginx throw `4023 pwrite()` error when proxying very large files

Tags: nginx, docker

We have an nginx daemon that acts as a proxy server for our micro services. We have a 2 nodejs severs talking with a nginx proxy in the middle.

When Server A posts a large CSV to Server B we get the following error"

```
 2019/06/24 14:02:50 [crit] 8#8: *4023 pwrite() "/var/cache/nginx/client_temp/0000000004" failed (12: Cannot allocate memory), client: 172.1.0.11, server: , request: "POST /core/api/source/upload HTTP/1.0", host: "web_core".
```

We have the following applied to our server block:

```
    proxy_request_buffering off;
    proxy_connect_timeout 600;
    proxy_send_timeout 600;
    proxy_read_timeout 600;
    send_timeout 600;
    client_max_body_size 0;
```

How do we configure the server and or nginx to properly proxy large files?

Comment: How did you create these containers?

Comment: @MichaelHampton - this is using the public nginx 1.17.X container from docker hub and deployed using docker swarm

Comment: Please add the relevant configuration (e.g. docker-compose.yml) to your question. It won't fit in a comment, and comments are temporary anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This was not an nginx issue. Things that helped me debug this:

4023 is not relevant - it was an id

pwrite() is a c system call

I found the PID of an nginx worker process and run `cat /proc/$PID/limits` and verified it had memory allocated.

Once all this was checked off, i then re assesed the network configuration and determined the issue was on an upstream nginx service which had a memory constraint smaller than the payload.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably related to:

- https://500.keboola.com/cp-in-docker-cannot-allocate-memory-part-2-369490f1a88f
- https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/651
- https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/43916
- https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=207273

TL;DR it seems the default dirty memory writeback threshold is triggered too late with containers with low memory limit, so writing to a file can result in memory error.

(because dirty pages are accounted for in the memory limit)
(then either `write` returns `ENOMEM`/12/`cannot allocate memory`, or the kernel invokes the OOMKiller on the process, possibly in newer kernel versions; I got the `pwrite` `ENOMEM` with linux 4.14)

This seems to occur because docker/kubernetes use cgroup v1 for which the `vm.dirty_ratio` threshold seems to be computed against the total (free) host memory, instead of the expected cgroup/container-local (free) memory.
=> if the memory limit is low relative to the total host free memory, then the dirty pages are *not* written back as usual, and the memory limit is reached during the write.
(with future cgroup v2 integration in docker/kubernetes and a recent kernel it should be solved, at least for most fs, cf https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/a1d21081a60dfb7fddf4a38b66d9cef603b317a9/Documentation/admin-guide/cgroup-v2.rst#writeback)

The possible workarounds seem to be:

- either drastically lower the vm.dirty thresholds, but it's per host, not per container, it could have performance impact
- or drastically increase memory limit for all containers doing disk IO...
- wait for cgroup v2 integrated in docker/kubernetes, cf future docker 20.03 and https://github.com/kubernetes/enhancements/blob/master/keps/sig-node/20191118-cgroups-v2.md